# java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer SharedPreference

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to read Integer data from SharedPreference

```
    public Integer readIntData(String key,int defaultValue){
           mSharedPref = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.shared_pref_app),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           return mSharedPref.getInt(key,defaultValue);
    }
```

when I call `int value = readIntData("key",1000);`

Always throws exception

> java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: You must have saved `boolean`  on same key previously. Check your code . Try after clear data.

Answer (score 11):

This error was occurred because you previously add some `boolean` value to this "key". Try to find some `putBoolean` in your code and check keys. Also try to reinstall current app to fix corrupted preferences.